# AS3, How to make a loop instead of using all these IF-statement

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, if-statement

As the title says, I need to find a way to do this Code, but in a more efficient  way.

```
    if (texten.texten.numLines < 3)
    {
    texten.texten.y = 0;
    texten.texten.height = 118;
    }
    if (texten.texten.numLines == 3)
{
    texten.texten.y =- 59;
    texten.texten.height = 177;
}
else if (texten.texten.numLines == 4)
{
    texten.texten.y =- 118;
    texten.texten.height = 236;
}
else if (texten.texten.numLines == 5)
{
    texten.texten.y =- 177;
    texten.texten.height = 295;
}
else if (texten.texten.numLines == 6)
{
    texten.texten.y =- 236;
    texten.texten.height = 354;
}
else if (texten.texten.numLines == 7)
{
    texten.texten.y =- 295;
    texten.texten.height = 413;
}
else if (texten.texten.numLines == 8)
{
    texten.texten.y =- 354;
    texten.texten.height = 472;
}
else if (texten.texten.numLines == 9)
{
    texten.texten.y =- 413;
    texten.texten.height = 531;
}
else if (texten.texten.numLines == 10)
{
    texten.texten.y =- 472;
    texten.texten.height = 590;
}
```

As you can see, this code will lower the textField (texten.texten is my textField within a movieClip) and raises the height of it (Making the text jump up whenever a new row is added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three ways to do this right now, a generic way using a loop, another one without a loop and a specific one based on your actual case :

**The generic method (with loop):** 
This is the less efficient method, and I mention it only because you specifically asked for a loop.
To replace a list of if/elseif like this one, you can use Arrays to store your data, dans loop through them to test the values :

```
// we store the numbers in tree Arrays
var lineValues:Array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var yValues:Array = [0, -59, -118, -177, -236, -295, -354, -413, -472];
var heightValues:Array = [118, 177, 236, 295, 354, 413, 472, 531, 590];

// we store and limit the numLines value to valid (for us) values
var numLines:Number = texten.texten.numLines;
numLines = (numLines > 10 ? 10 : (numLines < 2 ? 2 : numLines));

// here, we loop
for (var i:Number = 0; i < lineValues.length; i++) {
  if (lineValues[i] == numLines) {
    texten.texten.y = yValues[i];
    texten.texten.height = heightValues[i];
  }
}
```

**The generic method (without loop):**
This method use the same basis than the previous : store the data in an Array and then access it. But here, we access it directly.

```
// we store the numbers in two Arrays (no need for lineValues !)
var yValues:Array = [0, -59, -118, -177, -236, -295, -354, -413, -472];
var heightValues:Array = [118, 177, 236, 295, 354, 413, 472, 531, 590];

// we store and limit the numLines value to valid (for us) values
var index:Number = texten.texten.numLines;
index = (index > 10 ? 10 : (index < 2 ? 2 : index));

// index is in [2 -> 10]. Let's move it to [0 -> 8]
index -= 2;

// And that's it !
texten.texten.y = yValues[index];
texten.texten.height = heightValues[index];
```

**The specific method (no loop, no array):**
In your case, we can see that the values for each lines use a 59 increment. So, we can just calculate the position using numLines.

```
// we store and limit the numLines value to valid (for us) values
var numLines:Number = texten.texten.numLines;
numLines = (numLines > 10 ? 10 : (numLines < 2 ? 2 : numLines));

// and that's all
texten.texten.y = -((numLines-2)*59);
texten.texten.height = numLines*59
```

Comment: Thanks alot! :) I tried all three of them, and they all worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a loop at all. There appears to be a pattern where it roughly looks like:
(just wrote it off the top of my head, didn't test it)

```
if(texten.texten.numLines > 2){
    texten.texten.y = -59 * (texten.texten.numLines - 2);
    texten.texten.height = 118 + (59 * (texten.texten.numLines - 2));

} else {
    texten.texten.y = 0;
    texten.texten.height = 118;
}
```

Comment: Hi, good code, but now if I get above 2 rows of text, the whole textField just flies up in the sky.

Comment: It should be "= -59" rather than "-= 59"

Comment: ah, finalman is right. I thought they were subtracting from whatever value texten.texten.y was, but they were just setting it to the negative value instead. Fixed it in my post.

Comment: This code works aswell :) thanks, I've tried all forms presented to me, and they all work. This is really good, cause now I learn more than one way to achieve this. Thank you